# Spring mvc java

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

There are certain controllers like: 
AbstractController AbstractUrlViewController MultiActionController ParameterizableViewController ServletForwardingController ServletWrappingController UrlFilenameViewController AbstractWizardFormController SimpleFormController.
And, we have stereotype controller as well i.e. @Controller.

So, my questions are:

1. When we are using @Controller annotation in our Spring MVC
   program how to know that Our @Controller annotation is implementing
   any of these controllers?
2. Which type of controller is more
   useful now a days?
3. Are we not using above mentioned controllers
   in company's project now?

Answer (score 2):

> When we are using @Controller annotation

Every time you write an MVC controller (you can also use RestController instead, if it's ... a REST controller, i.e. a controller that sends back response bodies, instead of forwarding to a view)

> how to know that Our @Controller annotation is implementing any of these controllers

The question dosn't make sense. An annotation doesn't implement anything. It's just metadata associated to a class.

> Which type of controller is more useful now a days?

None of the ones you listed. They're from older versions of Spring, and are now obsolete, and kept for backward compatibility.

> Are we not using above mentioned controllers in company's project now?

No, you are not. It's ALWAYS a good idea to read the documentation of the libraries and frameworks you're using. I don't think the classes you listed are even mentioned anymore. But the annotation-based controllers are, in details. That should lead you in the right direction.

These classes are not even in the latest stable version of Spring BTW (5.x), and are marked as deprecated in the previous, 4.3.x versions.